# Changing data-url or similar attributes on Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to access the data-url attribute of the following element so it could be replaced upon callback or as needed with jQuery / Javascript.

**What method will work to do this?**

```
<a id="twitter_link" href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="imdto" data-lang="en" data-url="http://mydomain.com/changeme">Tweet</a>
```

I've tried using `attr()`, `prop()` functions but returns undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of jQuery are you using?  In the latest version, it works like so:

```
$("#twitter_link").attr( "data-url" );
```

Awesome example!  http://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/taGBL/1/

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the data function (for example):

```
$(myElement).data('url')
```

Answer (score 2):

try to read the attribute with `$('#twitter_link').data('url');`

About jQuery `data()` method: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/